# Converting 3 gang switch to Sonoff 3 gang switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, smart-switch

original 3gang switch

[image]

I just converting my house from single phase circuit to 3 phase circuit.

i intend to convert that 3 gang switch to sonoff 3 gang switch.

i only discovered this single 3 gang switch come with 2 live source.

the problem is Sonoff switch can only support single live line.

intended configuration
[image]

so here is my modified configuration. i know this dosent work because the wires do not have neutral line.

can i still make it work?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @Robert Chapin, the OP is having trouble articulating the question, but should't we offer comments to get him to explain his exact question? Isn't the question, "How would I do this?" or "Why doesn't this work?"

Comment: When a residental structure wired in single phase is converted to 3-phase I would assume that lighting circuits would remain being powered phase to neutral. Is that correct? A few high powered appliances would be wired phase-to-phase (i.e., 208 V in the US) But are any appliances actually using 3-phase (L1-L2-L3)? Would any ordinary residental structure have a 3-phase motor?

Comment: Hal Im, are you actually in the midst of converting or are you just thinking about converting from single phase to 3-phase? What do you hope to gain by this? Do you want to get a powerful air conditioning unit that requires 3-phase? Do you want to install a large cooking stove that requires 3-phase?

Comment: to Robert chapin - you can close this thred uo to you. for me i ll still look for answer on internet.

Comment: to jim. converstion to 3 phase already done. thanjs for supporting

Comment: i found a way to create netural line. but cant figure it out how to power up the ssr.  any way for last resort, i can hack my wall and put another sonoff switch there to take care L2. which i am trying to avoid.

Comment: We know you're looking for an answer, but we're still looking for a question.  Are you trying to control 2 separate circuits using 1 switch?  Or are you trying to install 3 separate switches?  Or are you trying to figure out how a relay works?  What is it that you need to know?

Comment: sorry robert. i am trying to control 2 seperate circuts using 1 switch. the reason being i do not want to create another hole in the wall just for that circuit..  i didnt realise the contractor who did my home renovation have combine the two circus into one 3 gang switch. only realise when i start to replace my switches with smart switch. it caused lot of tripping until i realise what going on. i think, the reason why ssr did not trigger is because when i press the button, out 3 become live, and there 2 live line going into ssr, that the reason ssr did not trigger. i am /right/wrong.

Comment: In my part of the world it is considered dangerous to have more than phase going into a switch block.  Three phases would off the chart.   I would reconsider if you really need to do this.  Its only lights after all.

Answer (score 1):

> i am trying to control 2 seperate circuts using 1 switch.

So the first problem is that you have the wrong switch, designed for 1 circuit.  The easiest and best solution is going to be replacing the switch with the correct device(s).

> i start to replace my switches with smart switch.

There are too many questions here and not enough information.  We have no idea why you're installing smart switches.

> there 2 live line going into ssr

You're not following the label on the relay.  It requires "24 - 380 VAC".  If you connect the same wire to both screws then there's no potential, you have zero volts.

> can i still make it work?

Get the correct device.  Most triplex switches won't work here.  So you might need to gang up a duplex switch and a single switch.  Even a smaller triplex switch plus a single switch would work if you need more switches.  If the "original" switch was working, then I suggest reinstalling that switch and keeping it or finding an appropriate substitute.